# GROUP BY with ROLLUP

Tags: php, mysql, rollup

I have mysql query like this :

```
    SELECT branch,ifnull(cluster,'Total --->')AS cluster,COUNT(rs) AS point, 
        (SELECT SUM(rp) from full_mcd 
        where full_mcd.cluster=sefiia_registered_outlet_rs.cluster GROUP BY full_mcd.cluster) 
        AS RP FROM sefiia_registered_outlet_rs GROUP BY branch,cluster WITH ROLLUP
```

result:

```
---------------------------------
|Branch   |Cluster   |Point |RP |
---------------------------------
|branch a |Cluster 1 |1000  |200|
---------------------------------
|branch a |Cluster 2 |2000  |50 |
---------------------------------
|branch a |Total --->|3000  |50 |
---------------------------------
|branch b |Cluster 4 |1000  |120|
---------------------------------
|branch b |Cluster 3 |1000  |100|
---------------------------------
|branch b |Total --->|2000  |100|
---------------------------------
```

the result was good except row Total---> for column RP. how can i fix this ??

Comment: Did you try any of the thoughtful answers given to your [recent question from 2 hours ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448389/multiple-sum-in-mysql/40448446#40448446)

Comment: no i have found the answer for that. this is new question

Comment: `no i have found the answer for that` ... have you actually tried the answers?  You should give feedback on your first question rather than asking a new one.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i have give feedback for my first question. thanks